# Need help calculating sum of datatable columns

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the sum of each column in my data table to show up in the footer tag. The data comes from an API that was created using information from my Json file. Below is the information from my JSON file, as well as my jquery.

```
[{
    "Season": 2006-2007,
    "Team": "P4two Ballers Osnabrueck",
    "Games": 32,
    "FG%": 65,
    "FT%": 71,
    "Assists": 4.5,
    "Steals": 1.8,
    "Blocks": 1.5,
    "TRB": 11.9,
    "Points Per Game": 16.7
  },
  {
    "Season": 2007-2008,
    "Team": "TG Renesas Landshut",
    "Games": 26,
    "FG%": 67,
    "FT%": 68,
    "Assists": 5,
    "Steals": 1.2,
    "Blocks": 0.8,
    "TRB": 16.3,
    "Points Per Game": 14.5
  },
    {
      "Season": 2008-2009,
      "Team": "Head Attack Erding",
      "Games": 20,
      "FG%": 69,
      "FT%": 75,
      "Assists": 6.2,
      "Steals": 2.3,
      "Blocks": 1.2,
      "TRB": 17.1,
      "Points Per Game": 12.8
    },
    {
      "Season": 2009-2010,
      "Team": "Deportivo Espanol de Talca",
      "Games": 22,
      "FG%": 66.5,
      "FT%": 71,
      "Assists": 4.1,
      "Steals": 2,
      "Blocks": 2,
      "TRB": 11.6,
      "Points Per Game": 16.8
    },
    {
      "Season": 2011,
      "Team": "Club Trouville Montevideo",
      "Games": 8,
      "FG%": 65,
      "FT%": 75,
      "Assists": 4.8,
      "Steals": 3,
      "Blocks": 1.8,
      "TRB": 15,
      "Points Per Game": 25
    },
    {
      "Season": 2011-2012,
      "Team": "San Isidro San Francisco",
      "Games": 54,
      "FG%": 62,
      "FT%": 68,
      "Assists": 4,
      "Steals": 2.3,
      "Blocks": 1.1,
      "TRB": 13,
      "Points Per Game": 12.5
    },
    {
      "Season": 2012-2013,
      "Team": "Club Providencia",
      "Games": 48,
      "FG%": 64.5,
      "FT%": 70,
      "Assists": 6,
      "Steals": 3.8,
      "Blocks": 2.1,
      "TRB": 13,
      "Points Per Game": 25
    },
    {
      "Season": 2013,
      "Team": "Academia de la Montana",
      "Games": 17,
      "FG%": 59.9,
      "FT%": 62,
      "Assists": 1.5,
      "Steals": 1.2,
      "Blocks": 1,
      "TRB": 11.4,
      "Points Per Game": 18.4
    },
    {
      "Season": 2013-2014,
      "Team": "Baskets Vilsbiburg",
      "Games": 26,
      "FG%": 59.3,
      "FT%": 49.6,
      "Assists": 1.5,
      "Steals": 1.3,
      "Blocks": 2,
      "TRB": 14.8,
      "Points Per Game": 24.7
    },
    {
      "Season": 2015,
      "Team": "Pirates de Bogota",
      "Games": 20,
      "FG%": 59.3,
      "FT%": 54.8,
      "Assists": 1.7,
      "Steals": 2.3,
      "Blocks": 0.7,
      "TRB": 10.9,
      "Points Per Game": 14.3
    },
    {
      "Season": 2015-2016,
      "Team": "CD Tinguiririca San Fernando",
      "Games": 17,
      "FG%": 56.8,
      "FT%": 61.4,
      "Assists": 1.1,
      "Steals": 2.2,
      "Blocks": 0.9,
      "TRB": 11,
      "Points Per Game": 13.1
    },
    {
      "Season": 2016-2017,
      "Team": "CD Universidad Catolica de Santiago",
      "Games": 39,
      "FG%": 48.1,
      "FT%": 56.1,
      "Assists": 1.8,
      "Steals": 2.3,
      "Blocks": 0.7,
      "TRB": 11.6,
      "Points Per Game": 15.2
    }
    {
      "Season": "Career",
      "Team": " ",
      "Games": 329,
      "FG%": 66.8,
      "FT%": 65.2,
      "Assists": 3.5,
      "Steals": 2.2,
      "Blocks": 1.3,
      "TRB": 13.1,
      "Points Per Game": 17.4
    }
 ]

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      // $.getJSON(url, callback);
          $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gwjdg', function(json) {
        tableGenerator('#tableName', json);
      });
    });

function tableGenerator(selector, data) { // data is an array
  var keys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));// Get the keys to make the header
  // Add header
  var head = '<thead><tr>';
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    head += '<th>'+key+'</th>';
  });
  $(selector).append(head+'</tr></thead>');
  // Add body
  var body = '<tbody>';
  data.forEach(function(obj) { // For each row
    var row = '<tr>';
    keys.forEach(function(key) { // For each column
      row += '<td>';
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // If the obj doesnt has a certain key, add a blank space.
        row += obj[key];
      }
      row += '</td>';
    });
    body += row+'<tr>';
  })
  $(selector).append(body+'</tbody>');
}
</script>
```

I have tried time and again to get the sum of each column to transfer to the footer of my datatable. I tried using a footer callback function as well but it didn't seem to work, my table just became blank. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are u using jquery datatables library ? or u want sum of each column  in html table ?

Comment: I want sum of each column in html table. The table is constructed through using an api from my Json file. I'm trying to get the sum of each column to show in my table footer. However I can't figure out the code to have the sum show in my table footer. Any help would be appreciated. I'm a novice so bear with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code after this line `tableGenerator('#tableName', json);`

```
var column_numbers = [4, 6, 7];//place column number here
var total_array = Array.apply(null, Array(column_numbers.length)).map(x => 0);
var rows = $('#tableName tbody tr');
rows.each(function(tr_index, row) {
    $(column_numbers).each(function(array_index, column_number) {
        var temp_val = Number($(row).find('td:nth-child(' + column_number + ')').text());
        total_array[array_index] += (temp_val == NaN) ? 0 : temp_val;
    });
});
var result_array = Array.apply(null, Array($(rows[0]).find('td').length)).map(x => '<td></td>');
$(column_numbers).each(function(array_index, column_number) {
    result_array[column_number - 1] = '<td>' + total_array[array_index].toFixed(2) + '</td>';
});
$('#tableName').append('<tfoot><tr>' + result_array.join(' ') + '</tr></tfoot>');
```

This will get total of 4th, 6th and 7th column as specified in this line`var column_numbers = [4, 6, 7];`
if u need any help please ask :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It's greatly appreciated. The only problem is that I wanted to get the sum of the columns. Basically the average of the numbers instead of the total of the numbers. I tried adding a sum function within the code but it didn't seem to work. That's the only problem I'm still having. I need to get the averages of all the numbers instead of the total. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: replace this line `result_array[column_number - 1] = '<td>' + total_array[array_index].toFixed(2) + '</td>';` with following `result_array[column_number - 1] = '<td>' + (total_array[array_index] / rows.length).toFixed(2) + '</td>';`